# Union classes or class erasure for Firestore desereliazation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection that holds different data objects with no common key or values.
In Kotlin, this is represented by something like

```
sealed class Task()
data class WorkTask(val id: String): Task()
data class ReductionTask(val time: Date): Task()
```

I would like to deserialize the data from the Firestore collection in a way like:

```
val tasks = result.toObjects(Task::class.java)
val workTasks = result.filterInstance(WorkTask::class.java)
val reductionTasks= result.filterInstance(ReductionTask::class.java)
```

In summary, I would like to retrieve a union from Firestore `WorkTask | ReductionTask | OtherTask` that I would be able to hold in one list and later either filter or patternmatch by instance.

EDIT:
Currently, my workaround is to have 1 common key (`type`) that holds the type of the object:

```
inline fun <reifed T: Any> QuerySnapshot.deserializeByType(
    crossinline selector: (type:String) -> Class<out T>
): List<T> {

   return this.documents.map({ document ->
      val type = firestoreDoc.getString("type")
      document.toObject(selector(type))
   })

}

querySnapshot.deserializeByType<Task> { type ->
   when (type) {
      "WORK" -> WorkTask::class.java
      "REDUCE" -> ReductionTask::class.java
      ...
   }
}
```

And in theory, I could just provide a list of classes and let it try/catch to deserialize. But that seems to be hacky as hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Firestore SDK is implemented in Java, it doesn't know anything about Kotlin sealed classes.  It is working purely off what understands about JavaBean style POJO objects that use conventions for names of getter and setter methods on classes.  [toObject()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) is simply mapping the names of Firestore document fields to the getters and setters (obtained by reflection) on the provided class instance.  That's all.

Your workaround (or some variation of it) is currently the only viable option, since your code needs to make a judgement about which actual class is actually being represented by the document in question.  There's really no way for the Firestore SDK to know which class the document should populate - you have to tell it that.